# Is `Math.floor(a / a) == 1` guaranteed for any `a` such that `a / a` is not NaN?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

In view of floating point inexactness, is this equation guaranteed to be true for any arbitrary numeric value of `a`, for which the division operation `a / a` returns a numeric value?

```
Math.floor(a / a) == 1
```

Comment: Have you tried this when a is 0?

Comment: `Math.floor(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY/Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` is `NaN` (same for `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`)

Comment: What if `a` is within the domain of the division operator? (Edited question.)

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by the domain.  Mathematically, any real number besides zero is the domain.  But with JS numbers, the Infinities and zero are legitimate divisors, some of which lead to `NaN` results.

Comment: I mean any `a` for  which `a / a` is a number. (Added to question)

Comment: Note that `a / a != NaN` is *always* true, due to the special properties of NaN.

Comment: @ruakh: `0/0 //=> NaN`, `Infinity/Infinity //=> NaN`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I'm not sure quite what you're trying to say, but I suspect that you've misunderstood my comment somehow. (If it helps: note that `NaN != NaN`.)

Comment: @ruakh: Oh, yes, of course.  Sorry.  Not quite sure how that fits with the question or the discussion, though.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: The question title currently specifies "any `a` such that `a / a != NaN`", which technically means the same as "any `a`". (Fortunately, the OP's intended meaning is clear enough that it's not a big deal; but I thought it worth pointing out for education's sake.)

Comment: @ruakh: Absolutely.  I was watching the question since before that edit, and didn't notice the change.

Comment: @davide: I think you'd have to see how division is specified.  I don't know if the IEEE 754 specification requires a particular algorithm, or if the JS specification adds its own if not.  Since there would have to be division of identical mantissas involved, I wouldn't be surprised if this is guaranteed, but it would probably take some digging into the specs to be certain.

Comment: I suspect that if `a` is `volatile`, `Math.floor(a / a) == 1` may be false sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEEE 754 specifies the result of an operation is the exact mathematical result rounded to the nearest representable value (in a direction the user may specify—up, nearest, and so on). When the exact mathematical result is representable, it is the nearest value, and there is no rounding, so the result is exact. Therefore `a/a` is 1 whenever an exception does not occur.

If I recall correctly, JavaScript does not allow implementations to use excess precision (as, for example, C does). So `a/a` is evaluated as expected. Then `Math.floor(a/a)` is 1, and `Math.floor(a/a) == 1` is true.

Comment: And, an exception will only occur if `a` is +/-0, +/-Inf or NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it

```js
test(1);
test(0);
test(1E10000000000000000000)

function test(a) {
  console.log(a, Math.floor(a/a));
}
```

Answer: No